# Windows 10 OneDrive Can Not Sync Network Folder

Tags: windows-10, sync, nas, onedrive, cloud

I've recently moved my hard drive into my NAS and mapped it to my PC as drive `E:`. I'm trying to point OneDrive to the new network location of my folder but it is failing (Dropbox had no problem with this).

Below is the image showing the path of the folder (same as before, `E:\OneDrive\`)

[image]

And here is the error I'm getting:

> Your OneDrive folder can't be created in the location you selected.

[image]

Can someone please help me fix this as I only have a 120gb SSD and my OneDrive folder is over 200gbs.

Comment: If you want, you could just Map your OneDrive folder - therefore all your files are still up on the OneDrive cloud and won't get synced down to your PC.

Comment: @Darius I dont have the fastest internet so it will take a while to download some of the files (~6gb). I use OneDrive as a offsite backup.